# Existence of a global frame of a vector bundle $E$ over $\mathrm{S}^2\times \mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, obstruction-theory

Everything in this question assume the smooth structures.

Suppose a vector bundle $E \rightarrow \mathrm{S}^2\times \mathbb{R}^4$ of rank $r$ satisfies the following condition:

> $E_x := E\big|_{\mathrm{S}^2\times \{x\}}$ is trivial for each $x\in \mathbb{R}^4$.

I want to prove that $E$ is trivial as well.

Perhaps some facts in the obstruction theory might be help, but I don't know the theory yet.

Is there a proof or some useful facts to deal with this question?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you assuming that $E\vert_{S^2\times x}$ is trivial or are you trying to prove that this is true.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter, the condition saying $E\big|_{\mathrm{S}^2\times\{x\}}$ is trivial is given, and the target is to prove $E$ is trivial.

Comment: You should edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter I just edit it. Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with the result that states that if $f$ and $g$ are homotopic, then $f^*E$ and $g^*E$ are isomorphic?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese No, I didn't learn it yet. Is this question related to the fact that $\mathrm{S}^2\times \mathbb{R}^4$ is homotopic to $\mathrm{S}^2$ ?

Comment: Yes. If you allow the use of the fact in my comment, then it quickly follows from the hypothesis that $E$ is trivial.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the triviality of $E$ follows from the following (see Theorem $1.6$ of Hatcher's [*Vector Bundles and K-Theory*](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf)):

> Given a vector bundle $p : E \to B$ and homotopic maps $f_0, f_1 : A \to B$, then the induced bundles $f^*_0E$ and $f^*_1E$ are isomorphic if $A$ is compact Hausdorff or more generally paracompact.

Consider the maps $c : S^2\times\mathbb{R}^4 \to S^2\times\{x\}$, $(p, v) \mapsto (p, x)$, and $i : S^2\times\{x\} \to S^2\times\mathbb{R}^4$, $(p, x) \mapsto (p, x)$. The composition $i \circ c : S^2\times\mathbb{R}^4 \to S^2\times\mathbb{R}^4$, $(p, v) \mapsto (p, x)$ is homotopic to the identity, so $(i\circ c)^*E \cong \operatorname{id}_{S^2\times\mathbb{R}^4}^*E = E$. On the other hand, $(i\circ c)^*E \cong c^*i^*E = c^*E|_{S^2\times\{x\}}$ which is trivial because $E|_{S^2\times\{x\}}$ is trivial by assumption.

The above argument shows that it is enough to know that $E|_{S^2\times\{x\}}$ is trivial for a single $x \in \mathbb{R}^4$ to conclude that $E$ is trivial (and hence $E|_{S^2\times\{x\}}$ is trivial for *every* $x \in \mathbb{R}^4$). Moreover, by also considering $c\circ i$, the same argument shows that $E$ is trivial if and  only $E|_{S^2\times\{x\}}$ is trivial for some (and hence every) $x \in \mathbb{R}^4$.

More generally, if $X$ and $Y$ are paracompact, and $f :X \to Y$ is a homotopy equivalence, then $f^* : \operatorname{Vect}(Y) \to \operatorname{Vect}(X)$ given by $[E] \mapsto [f^*E]$ is a bijection. Here $\operatorname{Vect}(B)$ denotes the set of isomorphism classes of vector bundles on $B$.

---

Note, I did not specify whether these bundles are smooth or continuous and that's because it doesn't matter. Two smooth bundles are smoothly isomorphic if and only if they are continuously isomorphic. In particular, a smooth bundle is smoothly trivial if and only if it is continuously trivial.

Comment: These facts are stunning. Thank you!